# Can we make namenode work as datanode as well?

Tags: hadoop, cluster-computing

I have set up 2 node Hadoop cluster of version **Cloudera Hadoop 2.7.1**.:

1. namenode and
2. datanode.

Is it be possible to make namenode work as datanode as well?

Though in *namenode*'s HDFS-site.xml I have added *datanode* entry and in slaves I have added *namenode*'s host name still it is not working as *datanode*.

Here are my files :

```
# masters # : NameNode

# slaves # : NameNode
             dataprocessor1
```

**hdfs-site.xml**:

[image: hdfs-site.xml]

This hdfs-site.xml is from NameNode. Here in XML file I have added both properties for namenode as well as datanode.

Comment: can you pl share HDFS-site.xml, master and s;ave files

Comment: Hi @RajenRaiyarela I have edited the post. Thanks! I have set NameNode and dataprocessor1 against IP's in HOSTS file.

Comment: As per my knowledge in the multi-node cluster the NameNode is only responsible for the master responsibilities it doesn't perform DataNode responsibilities (This is one of the major advantages in hadoop when compare to others) so, I think it is not possible to make NameNode work as DataNode.

Comment: this hdfs-site.xml, slave and master of namenode looks fine. Just confirm on Datanode, slave file only has dataprocessor1

Comment: @RajenRaiyarela Thanks for the answer.!!!
Updating slaves file on datanode with only "dataprocessor1" does the trick..Thank you again.!!